# image is not coming from external css

Tags: html, css

```css
.box1{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('..\Images\3d-wallpaper-desktop-screen-download.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
<h1> web site name</h1>  
hi dfskjwes

</div>
```

file structure ( as standard) 
project-- css, js, Images
 can`t get image in background

Comment: How does your directory structure appear? Also, use `/`...

Comment: You need to use `/` not "\" - Clearly a path issue.

Comment: File structure as standard?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `\`. Instead, use `/` in your path.

```css
.box1{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../Images/3d-wallpaper-desktop-screen-download.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
<h1> web site name</h1>  
hi dfskjwes

</div>
```